# How to get data from firestore using flutter streams

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: _fireStore.collection('messages').orderBy('creation',descending: 
                                                                              true).snapshots(),
              // ignore: missing_return
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                    ),
                  );
                }
//                print('i have data');
                print(snapshot.data.documents);
```

print(snapshot.data.documents); is printing null value.
'creation' is a timestamp field added into the fire store.

[image: this is the image of my data base]

https://github.com/umakanth-pendyala/Chat-app-with-flutter-and-fire-base 
is the link to my project in Github. And the code snippet is from the chat_screen page in the lib folder

Comment: Seems like you are on the Angela's training course at Udemy too. The same screens names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                    ),
                  );
                }
               else if(snapshot.hasData){             
             print(snapshot.data.documents);
           } 
  return CircularProgressIndicator();
```

First you need to return a widget, next if you want to print the data then you need to check if the snapshot has data or no. In your code it will always print null since this is asynchronous.

---

After doing the above, also change the query to the following:

```
_fireStore.collection('messages').orderBy('created',descending: true).snapshots(),
```

Since you have a field called `created` in the document and not `creation`.

Comment: I have done what you have asked me to do and it seems that I am not getting any data and I am guessing that there is something wrong with  this 'stream: _fireStore.collection('messages').orderBy('creation',descending: 
                                                                              true).snapshots()',

Comment: Add a screenshot of ur database

Comment: I have added the screenshot. if i replace stream: _fireStore.collection('messages').orderBy('creation',descending: 
                                                                              true).snapshots(), to _fireStore.collection('messages').snapshots() then it works but the messages are not in the orderly fashion

Comment: Ohh god. That's a silly mistake. I will mark the answer correct right away. and thank you for the help

Comment: I am sorry to ask you this. but the solution you suggested works perfectly well. But even though i added orderBy method i see my chat messages in an unordered fashion. Can you help me out with that??

Comment: Please ask a different question and add the link here so I can check it. But add the code that you are using to order them and add them in a list..